# javascript: window.open throws invalid url error

Tags: javascript, url, window.open

I'm trying to create a javascript that opens .jpg and .pdf files in a new window, and I keep getting a very annoying error when clicking the file links. Translated from norwegian, the popup error says:

"**Invalid URL-address to page(site?):**".

When I click "ok" on that error message, the new pdf/jpg-window will open as expected.

How do I get rid of the completly redundant error message?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("OpenPDFInNewWindow()"); 

    function OpenPDFInNewWindow()
    {      
      var aAllLinks = document.links;     
      for(var i=0;i<aAllLinks.length;i++)
      {
         var oA = aAllLinks[i];
         var sHREF = oA.href.toLowerCase();

         if(sHREF.indexOf(".jpg") > 0 || sHREF.indexOf(".pdf") > 0)
            oA.href="javascript:window.open('"+oA.href+"','test','width=300').focus();";
      }
    }
    </script>
```

The script checks the page for a-tags containing relevant file extensions, and then adds the window.open command in their href attribute.

I have tried IE9 and Chrome, both browsers throw same expection. It is important that this works in IE. I have tried many different combinations of arguments in the window.open call. The oA.href call returns an url like this:

```
http://<server>/arbeidsrom/ET24130/dokumenter/image.jpg
```

I'm a rookie on javascripts, so please keep that in mind when replying :)

(code snippet nicked from Randy Williams @ http://www.synergyonline.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=18)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
if(sHREF.indexOf(".jpg") !=-1 || sHREF.indexOf(".pdf") !=-1) {
  oA.onclick=function() {
    var w=window.open(this.href,'test','width=300'); 
    if(w) {
      w.focus(); 
      return false
    }; 
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you mplungjan, that did it!

Answer (score 0):

It's because most browsers don't have a native function for displaying file formats other than web-based ones. Especially `.pdf`. You probably have a `.pdf` plugin installed for IE and not for other browsers. I would suggest rather than what youre doing, open a new page which ***contains*** a `.pdf`, not ***is*** one.